# How to prevent two volume claims to claim the same volume on Kubernetes?

Tags: volume, kubernetes, claims

On my Kubernetes cluster on GKE, I have the following persistent volume claims (PVCs):

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: registry
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
```

and:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: postgresql-blobs
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
```

Amongst others, I have the following persistent volume defined:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: pv0003
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    - ReadOnlyMany
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: registry
    fsType: ext4
```

Now, both claims claimed the same volume:

```
bronger:~$ kubectl describe pvc postgresql-blobs registry
Name:           postgresql-blobs
Namespace:      default
Status:         Bound
Volume:         pv0003
Labels:         <none>
Capacity:       100Gi
Access Modes:   RWO,ROX


Name:           registry
Namespace:      default
Status:         Bound
Volume:         pv0003
Labels:         <none>
Capacity:       100Gi
Access Modes:   RWO,ROX
```

Funny enough, the PV knows only about one of the claims:

```
bronger:~$ kubectl describe pv pv0003
Name:           pv0003
Labels:         <none>
Status:         Bound
Claim:          default/postgresql-blobs
Reclaim Policy: Retain
Access Modes:   RWO,ROX
Capacity:       100Gi
Message:
Source:
    Type:       GCEPersistentDisk (a Persistent Disk resource in Google Compute Engine)
    PDName:     registry
    FSType:     ext4
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug and is fixed by https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/16432

Comment: What if it happens as of today ?