# Always collocate pod with pvc and gce persistent disk

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am creating a deployment that is going to use a GCE persistent disk to create a volume for the deployment's pod to use.

Since the pod is ephemeral, it may so happen that upon restarts, it ends up on a different node than the PD/PV/PVC.

In that case the following error may occur

```
Multi-Attach error for volume Volume is already exclusively attached
```

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46893114/2409793) answer.

My question is whether there is a way of predictably / consistently collocating the pod that needs the volume and the PD on the same node so as to avoid restart delays.

Answer (score 1):

Add a label to the node that includes the name of the PVC or a common label used by the PV and PVC, you can then use [node selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) to ensure that the pod (or pods) always get scheduled to that node. This is not the most scalable method and also not very resilient because you'll have a single point of failure.

You may also want to consider using StatefulSets since those can include a PersistentVolumeTemplate which will provision the PVC (which will dynamically provision the PV). The StatefulSet will also try to keep a pod on the same node to maintain state.