# when node down, get "Multi-Attach" error. on kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am using "ReadWriteOnce".
when node down, get "Multi-Attach" error.

```
Volume is already exclusively attached
```

The Test scenario is as follows.

1. kill node.
2. Pod status changes to "Terminating" after 5 minutes. (Force deletion in case of statefulset.)
3. The node is created in another node.
4. "Multi-Attach" error occurs.(Only nodes using PVC.) Until the dead node lives.

Is there any way to solve this problem?
Even if the node does not survive, I want to launch it on another node normally.

Comment: is there any rule of affinity or anything due to that pod getting stuck on specific node ? or there no rule of node selector and affinity ?

Comment: @HarshManvar there is no rule of node selector and affinity. The guide below was helpful. i shouldn't be forced to delete it. i have to find another way..

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/force-delete-stateful-set-pod/

Comment: Could you please share your environment data? Cluster type, version and yamls you used for setting it up

Answer (score 0):

As someone has already provided an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46893114/16425408)

Changing the access mode to ReadWriteMany would help, as it has write access on multiple Nodes at the same time