# Kubernetes Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc "Volume is already exclusively attached to one node and can't be attached to another"

Tags: kubernetes, vmware, vsphere, kubernetes-pvc, persistent-volume-claims

Kubernetes version:
V1.22.2

Cloud Provider Vsphere version 6.7

Architecture:

- 3 Masters
- 15 Workers

What happened:
One of the pods for some "unknown" reason went down, and when we try to lift him up, it couldn't attach the existing PVC.
This only happened to a specific pod, all the others didn't have any kind of problem.

What did you expect to happen:
Pods should dynamically assume PVCs

Validation:
First step: The connection to Vsphere has been validated, and we have confirmed that the PVC exists.
Second step: The Pod was restarted (Statefulset 1/1 replicas) to see if the pod would rise again and assume the pvc, but without success.
Third step: Made a restart to the services (kube-controller, kube-apiserve, etc)
Last step: All workers and masters were rebooted but without success, each time the pod was launched it had the same error ""Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc......" Volume is already exclusively attached to one node and can't be attached to another""

When I delete a pod and try to recreate it, I get this warning:
Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-xxxxx" The volume is already exclusively attached to a node
and cannot be attached to another

Anything else we need to know:
I have a cluster (3 master and 15 nodes)

Temporary resolution:
Erase the existing PVC and launch the pod again to recreate the PVC.
Since this is data, it is not the best solution to delete the existing PVC.

> **Multi-Attach error for volume "pvc-xxx" Volume is already
> exclusively attached to one node and can't be attached to another**

[image: ERROR]

Comment: add your pv and pvc yamls

Comment: Have you tried updating the Kubernetes version to 1.24?

Comment: follow this thread:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46887118/volume-claim-on-gke-multi-attach-error-for-volume-volume-is-already-exclusivel might help you here

Answer (score 4):

A longer term solution is referring to 2 facts:

1. You're using `ReadWriteOnce` [access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) where the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node.
2. Pods might be schedule by K8S Scheduler on a different node for multiple reason.

Consider switching to `ReadWriteMany` where the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes.